# Phase transition in Ising Model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, field-theory, phase-transition, ising-model

Consider the NN Ising model as
\begin{equation}
H = -J \sum_{<ij>} \sigma_{i} \sigma_{j} - h \sum_{i} \sigma_{i}
\end{equation}
This model has a global $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ symmetry in the absence of $h$. We know that phase transition occurs when $d>1$.

We can write the continuum field theory for that model as -
\begin{equation}
F[m] = \int d^dx \Big[\frac{t}{2}m^2(x) + u m^4(x) + \dfrac{K}{2}(\nabla m)^2+.......-h \cdot m\Big]
\end{equation}
It has a symmetry of $m \to -m$ in the absence of $h$.

My question is: Any phase transition that breaks the $\mathbb{Z_{2}}$ symmetry is always a continuous (2nd Oreder) transition or not (1st order)? How do we prove that statement rigorously?

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no reason for such a phase transition to be necessarily of second order. In fact, in the one-dimensional Ising model with formal Hamiltonian
$$
-\sum_{i,j\in\mathbb{Z}} J_{|j-i|} \sigma_i\sigma_j
$$
with $J_r \sim 1/r^2$, it is [known](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01022985) that the phase transition is first order (in the sense that the spontaneous magnetization is discontinuous at $\beta_c$).

On the other hand, for the nearest-neighbor Ising model on $\mathbb{Z}^d$, $d\geq 2$, [it has been proved](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-014-2093-y) that the phase transition is always continuous (note: when $d \geq 4$, this result [had been known](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01011304) for decades). Their argument also applies to the one-dimensional model when $J_r\sim r^{-\alpha}$, $1<\alpha<2$ (moreover, it is well known that there is no phase transition when $\alpha >2$).

The rigorous proofs are rather technical and I shall not even attempt to explain them here. If you are interested, the papers cited above contain all the relevant information.